# Deleting S3 files with wildcard in path using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I have files in an s3 bucket that are named something like:

```
/prefix/random_string_1/file123
/prefix/random_string_2/file678
/prefix/random_string_3/file286
/prefix/random_string_4/file397
/prefix/random_string_5/file003
```

I need to delete a particular file. I know the prefix and the filename, but I don't know the random_string part.

Currently, I am using:

```
boto3.resource(...).Bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='prefix')
```

and then iterating over all the results to find the filename that I need to delete.

Unfortunately, there are too many files (even with the same prefix), and it is taking too long to iterate over all of them.

I want to be able to get back a list of files matching "/prefix/*/filename" so that I can get a reference to the exact file that I want to delete.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: please can you explain more about your code what exactly u want? its not clear

Comment: you can create a any table which will hold the path as well as the filename which u want to delete or either you can give as a hardcoded string value then its easy to find the file in the AWS and then u can apply the deleting operation

Comment: Doesn't look like [the API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html) supports anything that Boto isn't exposing. Can you reconsider your naming scheme?

Comment: @brunns If I understand what you're saying, it's that S3 ITSELF does not support an optimized way of doing this type of search, so short of changing the naming scheme, there's nothing that will be more efficient than what I'm already doing. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly so. There is @snehilsingh's suggestion of building and maintaining your own directory, too, but I don't know how practical that is for you.

Comment: @JoeMjr2 When you say "it is taking too long to iterate over all of them", are you referring to the time taken to _retrieve_ the list of files, or the time to _filter_ the returned list of files to find the one of interest? If it is the listing process, how many objects are in your S3 bucket? Is this an operation you will frequently perform, or is it rare? I ask this because you might want to use [Amazon S3 Inventory - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to obtain a daily listing of all objects in the bucket.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I mean the time to filter the returned list of files in Python after they're retrieved. There are about 150K files, and it is done relatively frequently. I'll find another way to solve my issue.

Comment: To filter the list of files in Python should be sub-second, since all the data is in memory. Can you edit your question and include the code you are using to filter the list?